Unable to create table on Mounted Drive in Databricks: No parent external location found for path
Whenever I attempt to create a table using below code to a Mounted drive in ADLS Gen 2 I get the error:
No parent external location found for path

%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable USING csv OPTIONS (path "abfss://mnt/lake/RAW/circuits.csv");

However, when I attempt to create the table using the full path including the storage account name I have no problems:
%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event5 USING csv OPTIONS (path "abfss://root@xxxxxxxxiukadlsdev.dfs.core.windows.net/RAW/circuits.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True);

Also, if I attempt to create the table without prepending with abfss I get the error:
AnalysisException: [RequestId=b845fe0c-0788-4ead-82fd-8c9a686aa2ef ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] GenerateTemporaryPathCredential uri mnt/lake/RAW/allraces.csv is not a valid URI. Error message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Missing cloud file system scheme.


%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable USING csv OPTIONS (path "mnt/lake/RAW/circuits.csv");

What is interesting is I no problems reading the same file using the same path:
test = spark.read.csv("/mnt/lake/RAW/circuits.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

The the fact that I'm able to read the file would suggest that I have mounted the drive successfully. This can been seen from the output from display(dbutils.fs.mounts())

The strangest thing is that when I attempt to create the same table from my Databricks Community Edition using the same Mounted Drive I have no problems,see below. I just seem to be having this issue with Azure Databricks

Any thoughts?
Just wanted to update the question to show that my test to the ADLS Storage account is successful. So I really don't understand why I'm getting the error:


In file path after /mnt give mount point not container name you  already mounted till container.

Hi @DileepRajNarayanThumula, I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you mention 'after /mnt give mount point not container name you already mounted till container'?

Can you provide your mount code?


No parent external location found for path

The above ERROR indicates that the system cannot find the specified path

AnalysisException: [RequestId=b845fe0c-0788-4ead-82fd-8c9a686aa2efErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] GenerateTemporaryPathCredentialuri mnt/lake/RAW/allraces.csv is not a valid URI. Error message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Missing cloud file system scheme.

The error message is indicating that missing the file system scheme in the path you are providing
In Databricks, when reading data from Azure Data Lake Storage, you need to include the correct scheme for the specific cloud storage service.
I have tried the below approach:

display(dbutils.fs.mounts())

Results:
/mnt/raw    abfss://folder02@dilipstg02.dfs.core.windows.net/   

As I have already mounted till raw folder.
So Now I have created a new folder Lake and then I have created the table using the below
CREATE  TABLE  IF  NOT  EXISTS event5 USING csv OPTIONS (path  "/mnt/raw/lake/Customer.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

Results:
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/raw/lake/Customer.csv', name='Customer.csv', size=132, modificationTime=1721132445000)]

 df = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("dbfs:/mnt/raw/lake/Customer.csv")
df.show()

Results:
+---+----------------+--------------------+------------+
| ID|            Name|               Email|LastModified|
+---+----------------+--------------------+------------+
|  1|John Doe Updated|john.doe@example.com|  2023-05-24|
|  4|   Lisa Anderson|lisa.anderson@exa...|  2023-05-22|
+---+----------------+--------------------+------------+

